# appcfg.py migrate_traffic using app engine modules

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm attempting to use appcfg.py migrate_traffic, but I get a 500 error when using this with a module.  The documentation states that a module can be specified:

```
The 'migrate_traffic' command gradually gradually sends an increasing fraction
of traffic your app's traffic from the current default version to another
version. Once all traffic has been migrated, the new version is set as the
default version.

app.yaml specifies the target application, version, and (optionally) module; use
the --application, --version and --module flags to override these values.

Can be thought of as an enhanced version of the 'set_default_version'
command.
```

If I try this with a module, I get the following error

```
Error 500: --- begin server output ---

Server Error (500)
A server error has occurred.
--- end server output ---
```

The source at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py?r=396 (MigrateTraffic) doesn't seem to use the module at all.  Is this a bug in appcfg.py or a missing feature of app engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a ticket with google support.  The answer is that modules are not supported with migrate_traffic yet.  No ETA on when they might be supported.  I think the current version of appcfg.py doesn't mention modules as prominently in the help for migrate_traffic as well.